# I want to filter out items that are not pairs from this array let (pairsByIndexRaw = [[0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], null, [1], false, "whoops"];)

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

This is the array I am working with I want to remove the null, false and "whoops" using the filter method

```
let pairsByIndexRaw = [[0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], null, [1], false, "whoops"];
```

Comment: Do you have specific questions about this process?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Do you want this result [[0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1]] ?

Answer (score 2):

You can check it by using `Array.isArray()` method.

```js
const filtered = pairsByIndexRaw.filter(pre => Array.isArray(pre))
```

`Array.prototype.filter` will loop over each element in your array, if it returns true **In case if element is array** then the element is added to the `filtered` array otherwise it is skipped.

### If you only need pairs then

```js
const filtered = parisByIndexRaw.filter(pre => Array.isArray(pre) && pre.length === 2)
```

The snippet above will check if the item is an array and has exact length of two.